# Использование класса, как ключа массива

Tags: php

Изучал туториал по slimFramework и увидел там такой код:

```
    return [
  'settings' => function () {
    return require __DIR__ . '/settings.php';
  },
  App::class => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    AppFactory::setContainer($container);

    return AppFactory::create();
  },
  ResponseFactoryInterface::class => function(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return $container->get(App::class)->getResponseFactory();
  },
  ErrorMiddleware::class => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    $app = $container->get(App::class);
    $settings = $container->get('settings')['error'];

    return new ErrorMiddleware(
      $app->getCallableResolver(),
      $app->getResponseFactory(),
      (bool)$settings['display_error_details'],
      (bool)$settings['log_errors'],
      (bool)$settings['log_error_details']
    );
  },
];
```

И на данный момент я не могу понять что происходит при вызове App::class => function()...?
В класс записывается значение которое приходит из анонимной функции? Где можно почитать об этом?

Comment: `App::class` - это полное название класса в виде строки. Соответственно ключ массива - простой текст. Значение - анонимная функция, служит для отложенной инициализации объекта.

Comment: "Анонимная функция, служит для отложенной инициализации объекта" - это паттерн Lazy initialization?

Comment: Можно сказать и так. Классические примеры выглядят по другому, но в целом работает по схожему шаблону

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.